# Rezise of the map necessary?

Tags: ros, local-costmap, global-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I m trying to load a blank map with a defined dimension of **[width, height] = [20, 20]** but still it displays in Rviz just a small white square of constant dimension 6x6. I read this tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d?distro=hydro#Robot_description_parameters) and I put the right parameter in the costmap file:

```
global_costmap:
   global_frame: /map
   robot_base_frame: /base_link
   update_frequency: 3.0
   publish_frequency: 0.0  # For a static global map, there is generally no need to continually publish it
   static_map: true        # This parameter and the next are always set to opposite values. The global map is usually static so we set static_map to true
   rolling_window: false   # The global map is generally not updated as the robot moves to we set this parameter to false
   resolution: 0.01
   transform_tolerance: 1.0
   map_type: costmap
   width:  20
   height: 20
```

and

```
local_costmap:
   global_frame: /odom
   robot_base_frame: /base_link
   update_frequency: 3.0
   publish_frequency: 2.0
   static_map: false
   rolling_window: true
   width:  16
   height: 16
   resolution: 0.01
   transform_tolerance: 1.0
```

and here my map yaml file:

```
image: blank_map.pgm
resolution: 0.01
origin: [0, 0, 0]
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196 # Taken from the Willow Garage map in the turtlebot_navigation package
negate: 0
width:  20
height: 20
```

Anyway I after many tries I foudn that the map is going to be resized every time I start the corresponding node:

```
[ INFO] [1412758776.217404554]: Using plugin "static_layer"
[ INFO] [1412758776.420654688]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1412758776.643031834]: Resizing costmap to 600 X 600 at 0.010000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1412758776.741877357]: Received a 600 X 600 map at 0.010000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1412758776.769172167]: Using plugin "obstacle_layer"
```

and I m quite sure that causes the problem.
[Here](http://answers.ros.org/question/92966/amcl-and-global-map-question/) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/141166/move_base-in-hydro/) I found similar problem but not the right solution.

How to solve this annoying problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194466/rezise-of-the-map-necessary?/) by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 893 on 2014-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I must say that the answer given by David was very helpful and works.
But I should admit that as a simple workaround I've created a bigger map using Gimp. Just create a brand new plane with the dimension you want, the above reported map dimension is the dimension in pixel of the image. So if you want to create a map 20x20 [meter], just create with Gimp a page 2000x2000, save it as .pgm file and you are done. The big vantage is that you don t need to play too much with your global and local_costmap files. The map is going to be visualized in RViz very nicely.

The second thing that I discovered is that the origin of your map must be **integer**, since double doesn't work.
So if you have let's say:

```
image: my_map.pgm
resolution: 0.01
origin: [-10, -10, 0]
occupied_thresh: 0.65
free_thresh: 0.196 # Taken from the Willow Garage map in the turtlebot_navigation package
negate: 0
width:  20  # m   Don't forget to create a file with 2000 pixel width
height: 20  # m   Don't forget to create a file with 2000 pixel height
```

then put origin **[-10,-10,0]** as **int** and not as double or float.

I hope that it helps

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2014-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you use a static costmap layer, the global costmap is automatically set to the size of that costmap.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2014-10-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2014-10-08**:
Hello David. Since ths static costmap layer is something new for me, do you mean that the following [link](http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20New%20Layer#Grid_Layer) could help me? Am I pointing to the right direction?

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2014-10-08**:
That's probably not what you want. I would set static_map to false in your global costmap.